# Something or other vs something or another?

Tags: grammar

Which of these two sentences would be correct?

1. I recall that he was out looking for something or another.
2. I recall that he was out looking for something or other.

Basically, should I use "something or another" or "something or other"?

Also, as an aside, should the question mark at the end of my previous sentence go inside the quotation marks or is it correct as it is?

Answer (score 2):

They're both grammatically correct, but the phrase you'll hear from native English speakers is *something or other*.  Perhaps you're thinking of "one thing or another", which is also a common turn of phrase in English.

Your question mark is correct as it is, outside the quotation marks.  (But my comma belongs inside, if you consult traditional style guides.)

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks.

Can you elaborate a bit on the quotation marks point? If you don't mind.

Comment: Can you give an authority backing up your claim that 'something or another' is 'grammatically correct'?

Answer (score 0):

Both are grammatically correct. You can use

```
Something or other
```

which is a usual way of representing.

Another method is

```
One thing or another.
```